# how to calculate count of liked messages

Tags: mysql

I have below table like:(this is sample table)

```
message_unique_id   user_profile_id like_flag
91084                 1201             1
91084                 1201             2
91084                 1201             1
91084                 1202             1
91084                 1202             2
91084                 1202             1
91084                 1202             2
```

Above table contains like messages details of particular table having its message unique id and those msgs are liked by different profiles
where `like_flag=1` means like msg and like_flag=2 means unlike msg

Now I want to calculate count of likes.

How do I calculate it.

For above table like_count should be 1.

How do I get it as 1.

i want like_count as 1 because if one msg is like by one user and again its unliked by that user then its like_count becomes 0 and if that user again like that same msg then like_count for that msg becomes 1 like that

in above table there is only one msg : 91084 which is liked and unliked by two profiles 1201 , 1202 but 1201 again like that msg so total like_count becomes 1

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which is likely to prove problematic in due course.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY` to count the likes for each message, e.g.:

```
SELECT message_unique_id, SUM(IF(like_flag = 1, 1, -1)) AS likes
FROM messages
GROUP BY message_unique_id;
```

Or, with `CASE`:

```
SELECT message_unique_id, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN like_flag = 1 THEN 1 WHEN like_flag = 2 THEN -1 ELSE 0) AS likes
FROM messages
GROUP BY message_unique_id;
```

If you want to count total number of liked messages then you can simply use `COUNT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT message_unique_id)
FROM messages
WHERE like_flag = 1;
```

Comment: This solution does not account for like_flag=2 being an 'unlike' and subtracting from the count as per the OP.

Comment: The CASE statement is the correct solution based on the conditions stipulated in the original question. The IF would work but does not check for an 'unlike' being like_flag = 2, rather it's treated as an unlike if like_flag is not equal to 1.

Comment: `IF` statement assumes that there are only 2 values for `like_flag` and that's  what is mentioned by OP in the question.

Comment: The OP mentions 2 explicit values, 1 and 2, for like_flag in this example. I understand the assumption which would allow the use of the IF statement but there is no mention that there are only 2 values possible. If there are only 2 values possible, redefining unlike as -1 would allow the use of a simple SUM() which would remove any complexity from the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(like_flag = 1,1,-1)) as liked
SUM(IF(like_flag = 2,1,-1)) as unlike
FROM  messages
GROUP BY message_unique_id
```

Comment: by above query i get like_count as 4 and unlike_count as 3 but i want like_count as 1 because if one msg is like by one user and again its unliked by that user then its like_count becomes 0 and if that user again like that same msg then like_count for that msg becomes 1 like that

Comment: in above table there is only one msg : 91084 liked and unliked by two profiles  1201 , 1202 but 1201 again like that msg so like_count becomes 1

Comment: @MansiChaudhari whit this part you get 1(SUM(IF(like_flag = 1,1,-1)) as liked)

Comment: how this query gets  executed

Comment: means count(total_like),count(profile_id=1),count(profile_id=2)

Comment: SELECT 
SUM(IF(like_flag = 1,1,-1)) as liked
SUM(IF(like_flag = 2,1,-1)) as unlike
FROM  messages
GROUP BY user_profile_id  and write it in subquery or one more query

Comment: You should put some explanation in your answer. Code-only answers are not the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT message_unique_id,
       COUNT( NULLIF( like_flag, 2 ) ) AS liked,
       COUNT( NULLIF( like_flag, 1 ) ) AS unliked
FROM  table 
GROUP BY message_unique_id
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(like_flag) from tablename where Flag = 1;